# How to split line at a specified distance and getting coordinates of start and end points of each line segment？

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, line

I tried **v.split** in GRASS：
[image]

and my notebook ran a lot of time but showed this error：**bad allocation**, then I click "OK", and got nothing.

Are there other ways to split lines？and I hope to get 2 new columns in the same shapefile about coordinates of start and end points of each line segment.

Answer (score 4):

Which version of v.split are you using ?

1. from the GRASS Plugin
2. from the Sextante plugin

If you use the v.split from the GRASS Plugin, please read pp. 101-118 of the [QGIS manual](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.7.0_user_guide_en.pdf).

- you are not working in QGIS but in GRASS GIS and the input layer and the output layer are GRASS layers and not shapefiles (t1.shp) or QGIS layers, see [v.split](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.split.html).

  [image]

v.split in GRASS GIS

If you want to use directly a QGIS layer and  get a shapefile layer as result use one of the v.split from the Sextante Plugin (v.split.lenght and v.split.vert)

[image]

v.split.lenght with Sextante

You can also get the same result with Python and the Shapely module

Comment: I used sextante toolbox in QGIS, and the bad allocation error turned out, and then it was just like this：![Valid XHTML](http://imm.io/11WCX).

Comment: I use another computer(win7-64bit, QGIS1.80, SEXTANTE1.09), and got another different problem：[link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57233/problems-using-v-split-in-sextante-toolbox-to-split-lines)