# Are there only two methods of interpolation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I did recently a map of maximum temperature for specific area in Quantum GIS 1.8.0 and its interpolation. However, I was wondering if there are only two method of interpolation, apart from ‘Triangulated Irregular Network (TIN)’ or ‘Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW)’. Maybe is there any extra plugin for that?

Comment: I feel this is a QGIS weakness. Of the two one is TIN and the IDW is a bit of a black box and does not allow the user to set many of the input parameters. Good question and I hope we get some answers.

Answer (score 5):

If you will install [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/), you will have Kriging and Spline interpolation available via SEXTANTE plugin.

Comment: If you are going to install SAGA make sure that you get version 2.0.8. This is the one that Sextante expects. N.

Answer (score 3):

#### Okay I dug into this a little. I installed the OSGeo4W build of QGIS installed (1.8) with the Grass version it comes with.

#### In the Sextante tool box are all the various splines.

v.surf.xxx they are listed under.

#### Nearest neighbor analysis is r.resample

#### I see kriging is available (all the major ones) in Qgis via sda4pp [How to install SDA4PP plugin for Kriging in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21917/how-to-install-sda4pp-plugin-for-kriging-in-qgis)

So it seems most are available.

Comment: Thank you for help. I installed Sextante tool box but I have some issues, eg. I chose v.surf.idw or r.resamp.interp and I had message: "Could not load layer: C:\...tif", in logs: "Could not load model watersheds.model
ALGORITHM:saga:catchmentarea(parallel)".

Could you tell me why did I get the error?

Comment: no problem. Try this. If you go to the SEXTANTE configuration dialog, you will see a "GRASS" 
entry, and there is an option to enable console output logging. Enable 
it, run your GRASS command again...and then send the log information. this is the stack explanation. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57233/problems-using-v-split-in-sextante-toolbox-to-split-lines

Comment: I enabled console output logging and I have the error log as follows:
"Could not load model watersheds.model
ALGORITHM:saga:catchmentarea(parallel)"
"sextante.runalg("grass:v.surf.idw","C:/Users/Jarek/Desktop/granice/stacje1992.shp",12,2,"temperatur",False,"188032.55881,820240.953755,107812.241009,766913.732409",0,-1,0.0001,None)"