# IDW Interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I'm using the Interpolation plug-in in QGIS 2.18 to perform IDW Interpolation. I was hoping to specify a power of 2 and use the 10 nearest points to calculate the output, but I don't necessarily see a way to do so.

Is there another tool that I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If you go into Raster Tools>Analysis. There's Grid(interpolation), That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Raster > Interpolation > Interpolation

Select IDW interpolation method and click on the `wrench` icon on the right. It prompts you to enter distance coefficient. Choose this value wisely.

Refer the answer in [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78542/how-to-pick-the-coefficient-in-inverse-distance-weighted-method).